# Android ButterKnife

Tags: java, android, gradle, butterknife

I've installed `ButterKnife` my `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
}
```

My loginActivity looks like this:

```
package com.example.egen.forum;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your toast message.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btnLogin) public void test() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your toast message.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

The second toast does not show up. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't included annotation processor for ButterKnife code generation. Do it like described on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife):

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
}
```

And apply the plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
```

Otherwise, your code looks fine.

Explanation: ButterKnife library uses annotation processor for generating the code that provides the references to views and executes ButterKnife annotated methods. If you rebuild your project, and the AndroidStudio shows that the `@OnClick` annotated method is unused, then somethings wrong. If the annotation processor is provided and works correctly, it should show as used and lead to a generated method.

Comment: hi men.. i working with rxjava and buttknife(7). So rxjava working fine with butterknife for u??. i have problems.

Comment: @marlonpya RxJava and ButterKnife are two different, unrelated libraries, so I have no idea what you mean by "rxjava working fine with butterknife". Post a question if you have a problem.

Comment: it's ok. have problems in ejecuttion because buttknife not working. not forget add bind

Comment: @marlonpya please ask a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/ 
these comments are off-topic regarding this answer.

Comment: hi men this is mi issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44116936/buttknife-not-working-with-rxjava

Answer (score 1):

Add this line:

```
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
```

as well in your build.gradle.

See [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) for more info

Answer (score 1):

Well, Butterknife is yesterday, use databinding instead: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html. 
This is almost the same tool out of the box