# Buttknife not working with RXJava

Tags: android, gradle, butterknife

Have problems with two libraries.

**Gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pe.com.gmd.innova.adexus.adexusday"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
/*
greendao {
    schemaVersion 7
}*/
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile(name: 'androidgmd2', ext: 'aar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:greendao:3.2.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.9.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.8'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

not have problems with gradle process any error..

so have problems in ejecuttion application.. because my buttknife not working injection.

Maybe exist version so working fine with rxjava librarys ? or the version is really low

my version library `compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not importing AnnotationProcessor. 
Try this with latest versions:

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
```

Comment: Yes men. But my project is exist.. if change my gradle so change all project. I searching a solution with my version 7.0.1. 
Thanks bro.